# what is the alternative for Like operator in C#?

Tags: c#

Q: I want to match string with pattern that has wild cards(* and ?). I know in VB.Net, I can do this with Like Operator but how do I do in C#?

Example in VB:

```
Private Sub Match()
    Dim testCheck As Boolean
    testCheck = "apple" Like "*p?e"
End Sub
```

Q: Code in C#?

Comment: You will probably have to use regular expressions in C#

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C#, you can use regular expressions:

```
bool matches = Regex.IsMatch("apple", ".*p.e");
```

Replacing:

`*` with `.*` (multiple characters, zero or more)

`?` with `.` (one character)

Answer (score 9):

There is no operator like that in c#.

VB.NET compiles your code to following [`LikeOperator.LikeString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.likeoperator.likestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method call:

```
bool testCheck = LikeOperator.LikeString("apple", "*p?e", CompareMethod.Binary);
```

You can call this method directly if you add reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` and add using `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices`, but **I would not advise doing that**.

You should probably learn regular expressions and use proper regex instead of `Like` operator. Expression equivalent to yours would be:

```
.*p.e
```

Comment: Why you would not advise using LikeOperator.LikeString? Could you give more information? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, this is probably a job for regular expressions.

Nonetheless, I thought it might be fun to write a tiny extension method that implements this logic and came up with the following:

```
static class StringCompareExtensions
{
    public static bool IsLike(this string s, string s2)
    {
        int matched = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < s2.Length; i++)
        {
            if (matched >= s.Length)
                return false;

            char c = s2[i];
            if (c == '?')
                matched++;
            else if (c == '*')
            {
                if ((i + 1) < s2.Length)
                {
                    char next = s2[i + 1];
                    int j = s.IndexOf(next, matched + 1);
                    if (j < 0)
                        return false;
                    matched = j;
                }
                else break; // '*' matches rest of s
            }
            else
            {
                if (c != s[matched])
                    return false;
                matched++;
            }
        }
        return (matched == s.Length);
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
string s = "12345";
Console.WriteLine(s.IsLike("1*5")); // Returns true
```

Of course, you could write the same method using regular expressions, which would be shorter and simpler than the one above.

**EDIT:**

I had a little time to play with this today. I ended up writing an article that presents several ways you can get the functionality of the `Like` operator from C#. The article is [Implementing VB's Like Operator in C#](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/net/implementing-vbs-like-operator-in-c).

Comment: Dude ... Awesome!!! I like this.  Checking out your article now .....

Comment: I am really impressed by your initiative, but your function doesn't always work. I discovered that "*2345" doesn't match for "1234512345". Your function tries to line up the 2 in the first string with the FIRST 2 in the second string, and so it returns false. You would need to run a loop to try to line up the 2 in the first string with EVERY 2 in the second string. That is the only flaw I found.

Comment: @JoeGayetty: Yeah, the wildcard doesn't work correctly unless it's at the end of the pattern string. Guess I'll need to dive into that some time. It gets a little more complex after a wildcard to figure out where things match up again.

Comment: Thanks for attempting to implement this, however this fails for multiple test cases, such as matching "abcabc" with either "abc*" or "*abc". I should have read the comments but instead went straight to trying to use it before finding it doesn't work. If the code cannot be fixed then it would better be removed.

Comment: @XavierPoinas: It appears everything works except for the wildcard. Others have found it useful, so I'm not inclined to delete it. But perhaps I can find some time to implement the missing functionality.

Comment: Well, arguably the wildcard is the most important of the 2 special characters, as it is trivial to implement the question mark. Sorry I don't have any more test cases than the two I provided. I haven't tested the question mark. Maybe you could at least place a warning at the top of the answer stating that it only works for question marks...

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Like` in C#.  Use regular expressions to get the functionality you want.

You might want to start with this intro tutorial: [C# Regex.Match](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match)

Answer (score -3):

```
Regex.IsMatch("apple", "*p?e")
```

for simple pattern matching:

```
string.Contains()
```

Comment: This regex is not the equivalent of the expression in the question.